# Toggle one switch on and turn 2 others off

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having an issue with my application. I am trying to toggle one switch, and when this switch is toggled, all the other switched get toggled to off. I have tried using the onChange method. This method works for 2 of the switches on and off, but not for 3 or more?

Here is my attempted code:

```
import SwiftUI
import ToastUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var generatedNumber : Int = 0

@State var allNumbers : Bool = true
@State var evensOnly : Bool = false
@State var oddsOnly : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Your genenerated number:")
            .font(.bold(.title)())
        
        Text("\(generatedNumber)")
            .font(.bold(.custom("Generated Number Size", size: 60))())
            .foregroundColor(.cyan)
        
        VStack{
            Toggle("All numbers", isOn: $allNumbers)
                .tint(.cyan)
                .onChange(of: allNumbers) { newValue in
                    //When toggled, turn other switches off, but leave this one on
                    evensOnly = !newValue
                    oddsOnly = !newValue
                }
            Toggle("Even numbers only", isOn: $evensOnly)
                .tint(.cyan)
                .onChange(of: evensOnly) { newValue in
                    allNumbers = !newValue
                    oddsOnly = !newValue
                }
            Toggle("Odd numbers only", isOn: $oddsOnly)
                .tint(.cyan)
                .onChange(of: oddsOnly) { newValue in

                    allNumbers = !newValue
                    evensOnly = !newValue
                }
        }.padding(30)
            .toggleStyle(.switch)
    }
}
}
```

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Only one switch should be on at a time, and if a different one is toggled, to turn the other 2 off. The onChange method when doing this states: "action tried to update multiple times per frame." Does this mean that two @State reloads are trying to occur at execution times too close to each other? Please help me

Comment: You got a retain cycle. As you observe the change of all three `@State`, if you change one all other `.onChange` modifier will get called to. And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the first comment already said you got a retain cycle. To achieve your goal, there are many solutions to it. However, I would do it like that (see code snippet) using the MVVM pattern to achieve it.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var generatedNumber : Int = 0
    @StateObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your genenerated number:")
                .font(.bold(.title)())
            
            Text("\(generatedNumber)")
                .font(.bold(.custom("Generated Number Size", size: 60))())
                .foregroundColor(.cyan)
            
            VStack {
                Toggle("All numbers", isOn: $viewModel.allNumbers)
                    .tint(.cyan)
                Toggle("Even numbers only", isOn: $viewModel.evensOnly)
                    .tint(.cyan)
                Toggle("Odd numbers only", isOn: $viewModel.oddsOnly)
                    .tint(.cyan)
            }.padding(30)
                .toggleStyle(.switch)
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allNumbers : Bool = true
    @Published var evensOnly : Bool = false
    @Published var oddsOnly : Bool = false
    
    private var store: [AnyCancellable] = []
    
    init() {
        $allNumbers
            .sink(receiveValue: {
                guard $0 else { return }
                self.evensOnly = false
                self.oddsOnly = false
            })
            .store(in: &store)

        $evensOnly
            .sink(receiveValue: {
                guard $0 else { return }
                self.allNumbers = false
                self.oddsOnly = false
            })
            .store(in: &store)

        $oddsOnly
            .sink(receiveValue: {
                guard $0 else { return }
                self.allNumbers = false
                self.evensOnly = false
            })
            .store(in: &store)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked our perfectly for me! I had to import Combine for this however

Comment: You welcome :) - sorry yes I completely forgot to mention it to import Combine for it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly robust answer involving an array so now you haver a
dynamic `toggle` view.

```
enum numbersOptions: String {
                case all = "All numbers"
                case even = "Even numbers"
                case odd = "Odd numbers only"
            }

            struct OptionItem: Identifiable, Equatable {
                let id = UUID()
                let option: numbersOptions
                var isOn: Bool = false
            }

            struct ToggleTest: View {
                @State var generatedNumber : Int = 0
                @State var options = [OptionItem(option: .all, isOn: true), OptionItem(option: .even), OptionItem(option: .odd)]
                
                var body: some View {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Your genenerated number:")
                            .font(.bold(.title)())
                        
                        Text("\(generatedNumber)")
                            .font(.bold(.custom("Generated Number Size", size: 60))())
                            .foregroundColor(.cyan)
                        
                        VStack{
                            ForEach($options) { $option in
                                
                                Toggle(option.option.rawValue, isOn: $option.isOn)
                                    .tint(.cyan)
                                    .onChange(of: option) { updated in

                                        if updated.isOn {
                                            self.options = self.options.map({
                                                var optionItem = $0
                                                optionItem.isOn = $0.id == updated.id
                                                return optionItem })

                                            // ANY UPDATED BASED ON THE SELECTED ITEM

                                            switch updated.option {
                                            case .all:
                                                print("all seleted")
                                            case .even:
                                                print("eve seleted")
                                            case .odd:
                                                print("odd seleted")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(30)
                        .toggleStyle(.switch)
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]