# turn other toggles off in Swiftui

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift and swiftUI, so probably done something obvious wrong, but I display a list of toggles. When one of these is turned on, I want the others to be turned off, so only one of the items can be selected at once. I've got an array of toggles, and that works fine, but I can't get the 'turn off all the other toggles to work' without it giving compile errors. I'm getting errors on the follow lines.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsOl.png)

Here's all the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors:[SortDescriptor(\Book.timestamp)]) private var items: FetchedResults<Book>
    
    @State var doesClose:[Bool] = []
    
    init(numberOfBooks: Int) {
        
        var values: [Bool] = []
        for i in 0..<numberOfBooks {
            values.append(false)
        }
        
        _doesClose = State(initialValue: values)
        
        print(numberOfBooks)
        print(self.doesClose)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            
            List {
                ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element) { idx, item in
                              
                    HStack (spacing: 20){
                                             
                        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                            Text(item.bookName!)
                                                        
                            Toggle("", isOn: $doesClose[idx])
                                .onChange(of: doesClose[idx], perform: {for i in 0..<doesClose.count {
                                    if(i != idx)
                                    {
                                        doesClose[i] = false
                                    }
                                }})
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("List")
        }
    }
    
    private func turnAllOtherButtonsOff(onIndex:Int)
    {
        
        for i in 0..<doesClose.count {
            if(i != onIndex)
            {
                doesClose[i] = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried running the func at the perform stage with similar errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This migth help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211946/toggle-one-switch-on-and-turn-2-others-off/74212626#74212626

Answer (score 0):

Posting this if this helps anyone. I dropped the idea of going through the array, and just concentrated on keeping track of the previous index, and then switching that when there's an onChange. Here's the code.

```
 Toggle("", isOn: $doesClose[idx])
                                .onChange(of: doesClose[idx], perform: {value in
                                    print(value)
                                    if(value == true)
                                    {
                                        if(oldToggle != -1){
                                            doesClose[oldToggle] = false
                                        }
                                        
                                        oldToggle = idx
                                    }
                                    
                                    print(oldToggle)
                                })
```